# Date format help

Tags: 7, datetime

I am trying to add Japanese date Y年 n月 j日 in fields but the date is being displayed 2016年 2月 6日 年月日 .  I want to remove 年月日 at the end of the date it indicates year month and day. 2016年 2月 6日 is exact format of date and 年月日 this is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify new date formats here via: /admin/config/regional/date-time/formats

If you wanted to add or remove 年月日 to these dates, you can just enter it in there. If it doesn't show up an alternative way is to do a hook date format, check out: https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/programatically-creating-date-formats/

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the answer yet, here it is!

Simply add a '\' before each character.

So 'Y年n月j日' should become 'Y\年n\月j\日'

Source: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2011-04-30/custom-date-formats-write-dates-the-japanese-way#comment-6443784